# Save-As in Excel disconnects Windows DFS mapped network drive

Tags: windows, dfs, microsoft-office

Users can open and create files no problem. But when they save-as and click browse it disconnects the mapped drive to \domain\dfsroot and dumps them on the local file system.
I've been all over the internet and not found anything quite like this.
Not found any helpful events. It's affecting a bunch of users not one.

DFS is multisite but only one namespace and so far no replication. 
AD sites in correct (and double checked).
Any clues?

Comment: On a normal share does the problem arise ?

Comment: No normal shares or UNC path to the file server are fine.

Comment: Could be a buffer problem then. Can you test on a new created dfs share outside the other dfs path ?

Comment: (by buffer I mean staging, sorry)